# Styling subsets of a (non-unique) multi-level index data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, background-color

For illustration purposes, I have the following data frame:

```py
arrays = [
    np.array(['Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Josh', 'Josh', 'Josh', 'Josh', 'Josh', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter']),
    np.array(['Client A', 'Client A', 'Client A', 'Client A', 'Client B', 'Client B', 'Client B', 'Client C', 'Client C', 'Client D', 'Client D', 'Client D', 'Client E', 'Client E', 'Client E', 'Client E', 'Client E']),
    np.array(['Cars', 'Trains', 'Planes', 'Boats', 'Cars', 'Trains', 'Boats',  'Cars', 'Trains', 'Cars', 'Trains', 'Planes', 'Cars', 'Trains', 'Planes', 'Boats', 'Bikes'])
]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(17, 5)+100, index=arrays)
df.columns = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
df.index.set_names(['Sales person', 'Client', 'Product'], inplace=True)
```

Which is basically a sales overview by sales person / client / product.

For all the rows where Product is equal to Cars, I want to apply a background gradient to the sales numbers across the row. Similarly, for all the rows where Product is equal to Trains, I want to apply a text gradient. For the length of this post, I'll just focus on the background gradient part as the text gradient will be similar in terms of execution. As an extra, and I do not know if this is possible, for the cells that will not have a number I want them to have a grey background color and I want the cell of the index itself (so the index cells that contain Cars) to have the same grey background color. This would be nice to have, the primary focus is on the gradient background / text color of the different subsets.

I saw a similar post "How do I style a subset of a pandas dataframe?" which I tried to use as base and ended up doing the following:

With my color map being `cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["Red", "Green"])` and using index slicing I got

```py
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cmap, axis=1, subset=df.loc[idx[:, :, 'Cars'], :])
```

However this does not style the data frame as intended. The following warning occured:

> C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:342: FutureWarning: The behavior of indexing on a MultiIndex with a nested sequence of labels is deprecated and will change in a future version. `series.loc[label, sequence]` will raise if any members of 'sequence' or not present in the index's second level. To retain the old behavior, use `series.index.isin(sequence, level=1)`
> return method()

But this refers to the subsetting rather than the styling. I have also tried to subset it how it is suggested as in the warning but still get the same warning and no styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code throws a `KeyError: 'Monday'` in `2.1.1`.

Just fix the subset.

```
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["Red", "Green"])

idx = pd.IndexSlice
cars, trains = idx[:, :, "Cars"], idx[:, :, "Trains"],

d = {"Cars": "grey", "Trains": "lightgrey"}

(
    df.style
      # .set_properties(**{"background-color": "white"}) # optional
      .background_gradient(cmap=cmap, axis=1, subset=cars)
      .apply(lambda x: [f"background-color: {d['Trains']}"]*len(x), subset=trains)
      .text_gradient(cmap=cmap, axis=1, subset=trains)
      .map_index(lambda x: f"background-color: {d.get(x)}") # inner level by def
      # use `applymap_index` if using pandas <2.1.0
)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: So the original data frame is much larger and contains some NaN which is totally fine. Before applying the background gradient and text gradient I want the rows that contain "Cars" to have a darkgrey background colour, including the index "Cars" itself. Similary, for all the rows where the index is equal to "Train", I want the whole row to have a grey background colour, including "Train" itself. After this, I'll apply the gradient colouring as you suggested, so that later when there is a NaN value, the bg colour of that NaN value still corresponds with the original bg colour of that row.

Comment: How can you apply a background gray color and a gradient to the same cells (belonging to the `Cars` index) at the same time ? I'm confused! There is a missing piece you're not talking about or most likely you failed to describe your problem. The given example does not match the descriptions you're giving. You gotta provide a **clear** logic about the formatting and a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that matches your actual data.

Comment: Okay a bit differently then. After doing the background_gradient and text_gradient. Is there a way to change the background colour of the index? So "Cars" gets a dark grey background colour and "Trains" gets a light grey background colour?

Comment: Now, it makes more sense. See update.

Comment: I see that I failed to describe one more thing. For the rows containing "Trains", I see that indeed the cells with "Trains" got a light grey background colour. However, I forgot to mention that the rows of "Trains", so where the text_gradient is applied, also should have the same background colour, i.e. light grey. Can this also be incorporated?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I updated the answer to address that as well.

Comment: All the previous examples worked. However, as I am copying and pasting your latest answer I get the following error message:

.apply(lambda x: [f"background-color: {d["'Total'"]}"]*len(x), subset=Total)
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['

Which is strange, cause the brackets seem to match

Comment: That's because you made a typo when modifying `Trains` to `Total`. You want `[f"background-color: {d['Total']}"]*len(x), subset=Total)` and not `[f"background-color: {d["'Total'"]}"]*len(x), subset=Total)`